# How to create a slide with transparent letter LaTeX without using \pause?

Tags: beamer

I'd like to make the following codes into 2 slides separately in my presentation. But `\pause` can't help here, because I'd like to put the `first section` on the first page and `the second section` on the fifth.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Structure}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
The first section
\item
The second section
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a different overlay for each of the items. For example, if you want `The first section` on slide 1 (through 4) and `The second section` on slide 5, you can do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Structure}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1->
    The first section
    \item<5->
    The second section
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```